# Linq SUM on objects which have operator+?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, oop, sum

I've an object that represent a business data.

Basically, it's an object agregating some totals:

```
public class MyClass{
   public double MyDataOne {get;set;}
   public double MyDataTwo {get;set;}
   public double MyDataThree {get;set;}

   public static MyClass operator +(MyClass data1, MyClass data2){
      return new MyClass{MyDataOne = data1.MyDataOne + data2.MyDataOne, MyDataTwo=data1.MyDataTwo+data2.MyDataTwo, MyDataThree=data1.MyDataThree+data2.MyDataThree };
   }
}
```

Now, if I've an `IEnumerable<MyClass> myClasses`, Is there somethings I can implement in MyClass to make this:?

```
myClasses.Sum(d=>d);
```

Because for me, the way an object is additioned must be the knowledge of the object and not the caller(if one day I've one data more, I don't want to look in my whole code to see where it is used).

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13661394/1714342 it explains something

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Operator Overloading and Linq Sum in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661335/operator-overloading-and-linq-sum-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @StayOnTarget Are you really commenting a 9 year old thread? XD

Comment: @J4N I flagged it as a potential duplicate. The system adds the comment automatically, as it happens.

Comment: What's the point? There is already an answer here that has exactly the same content of the other question you reference? I don't really care, I'm just curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write your own extension method:

```
public static MyClass Sum(this IEnumerable<MyClass> source)
{
    var result = new MyClass(); // all data will be zeros

    foreach(var item in source)
       result = result + item;

    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
var sum = myClasses.Sum();
```

Comment: And if you can also make it more generic by introducing some interface called `ISumable` and make generic extension for all `IEnumerable<T> where T:ISumable` :)

Comment: @wudzik `YAGNI` :) He has only one business class with this behavior

Comment: @wudzik Thank you. I will just add that I create an interface, to ensure that class on which I sum implement a `Sum` method that takes an IEnumerable list in parameter. Like this I don't create many intermediate elements

Answer (score 6):

You can write your own extension method that wraps a call to `IEnumerable<T>.Aggregate` which in turn calls your overloaded `operator +`:

```
public static MyClass Sum(this IEnumerable<MyClass> collection)
{
    return collection.Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);
}
```

This would be called by:

```
MyClass sum = myClasses.Sum();
```

---

Or even go one step further, generalize, and include a selector:

```
public static MyClass Sum<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, 
    Func<T, MyClass> selector)
{
    return collection.Aggregate(new MyClass() /*start with an empty MyClass*/, 
        (a, b) => a + selector(b));
}
```

This would be called as you suggest:

```
MyClass sum = myClasses.Sum(d => d);
```

As well as from complex types containing a `MyClass` for example:

```
class Foo
{
    public MyClass Bar {get; set;}
    public int Baz {get; set;}
}

var FooList = new List<Foo>();

MyClass sumOfFooListsBars = FooList.Sum(f => f.Bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `Sum` you should provide `Func<MyClass, ###>` delegate, where `###` is `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, `decimal` or their nullable counterparts.
So you are not able to use `MyClass` in the way you want.

All overloads of `Sum` method returns primitive types that I mentioned above. That's why it doesn't make sense to sum custom object while returning type is not a number but custom object too.

Answer (score 0):

A tad late perhaps...

but if the goal is to sum the classes using the implemented `+`-function (and not necessarily to use the `Sum()`-function) you can use the `Aggregate()`-function

```
List<MyClass> myClasses;
...

MyClass myClassSum = myClasses.Aggregate(func: (result, item) => result + item);
```